# Undeclared enum?

Tags: c, enums

While compiling this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Boolean
{
    TRUE,
    FALSE
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d", Boolean.TRUE);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting:

> error: 'Boolean' undeclared (first use in this function)

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, you don't access individually enumerated constants using the syntax `EnumType.SpecificEnum`. You just say `SpecificEnum`. For example:

```
printf("%d", TRUE);
```

When you write

```
printf("%d", Boolean.TRUE);
```

C thinks that you're trying to go to the `struct` or `union` named `Boolean` and access the `TRUE` field, hence the compiler error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, very clear! Is there any way to use the `EnumType.SpecificEnum` syntax?

Comment: @cdonts To the best of my knowledge, C doesn't support this. In C++, you can use `enum class` to do this, though the syntax will be `EnumType::SpecificEnum` (and C++ is a different language.)

Comment: In c, that is not possible.

Comment: Good, thanks for the extra info! I'll accept this :-) (just need to wait 10 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Just write TRUE without Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Boolean { FALSE, TRUE };

struct {
    const enum Boolean TRUE;
    const enum Boolean FALSE;
} Boolean = { TRUE, FALSE };

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", Boolean.TRUE);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrote `Boolean.` Just write `TRUE` or `FALSE` without that prefix.