# Correct usage of enum members in C

Tags: c

If i have an enum in a header file aheader.h as

```
enum Fruits
{
  Apple,
  Orange,
  Guava
};
```

Can i use it in another header bheader.h as

```
#include <aheader.h>
...
#define FRUIT1 Fruits.Apple
```

Is this usage correct, for whatever purpose I intend to use it for.
What would be the scope changes if any?

Comment: You can use `Apple` name directly without having to go through a `#define` directive.

Comment: The `.` isn't accepted syntax, here. It only can be used for the fields of `union` or `struct` *instance*.

Comment: t is possible to write like this if you prepare a structure such as a global variable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23035495/971127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enum constants aren't qualified by their parent type in C, so that'd be simply:

```
#define FRUIT1 Apple
```

For this reason, it is often considered good style to prefixing the enum constants yourself to avoid name collisions.

```
enum Fruits
{
  FRUIT_APPLE,
  FRUIT_ORANGE,
  FRUIT_GUAVA
};
```

Comment: This style you proposed is concise; but why does the one I wrote gives me my result - any reasons for it not being wrong?

Comment: @sprkv5: Your version is a syntax violation. I don't know if there are compilers supporting this syntax, though.

Comment: @sprkv5: `#define FRUIT1 Fruits.Apple` in itself isn't wrong, as its just another pre-processor statement. The mistake will become obvious when you use `FRUIT1` in the code itself like in: `int f = FRUIT1;`.